# Error when deploying asp.net MVC4 application in iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Account'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method[image] that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two AccountController classes. One in `P247.ComplianceTracker.MVC.Controllers` and another one in `P247.CoachingTool.Mvc.Controllers`.

The component (Dependency Resolver) that resolves the controllers does this by convention. That means it looks for a class that inherits from Controller, and follows a naming convention (AccountController when the controller is set to account in a request). Both libraries have classes that match the criteria (or in both namespaces exists a class which matches this criteria).

So you have several options:

1. rename one of your AccountController classes
2. change the mapping (as the error proposes)

In `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions` is a `MapRoute` extension taking a list of namespaces as a parameter:

`public static Route MapRoute ( this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, string[] namespaces );`

So your registrations could be changed to something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute (
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      namespaces: new string [] { "P247.CoachingTool.Mvc.Controllers" }
  );

routes.MapRoute (
      name: "Default",
      url: "compliance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      namespaces: new string [] { "P247.ComplianceTracker.MVC.Controllers" }
  );
```

Requests routed to account/index would be handled by `P247.CoachingTool.Mvc.Controllers.AccountController`, requests to comliance/account/index by `P247.ComplianceTracker.MVC.Controllers.AccountController`.

Note: Urls do change, so you might need to change some markup or calls to helper functions.

Side note: Code compiles on my machine, I do not have a comparable setup, sou you might need to adjust to your specific setup.